# object references an unsaved transient instance - despite Cascade

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, cascade

I am getting a TransientObjectException

```
       org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance 
- save the transient instance before flushing: EntityB.entityA -> EntityA
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:376)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:454)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:671)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:663)
        at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:346)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:291)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:239)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
```

These two entites have a OneToOne relationship:
In EntityA

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_B_ID")
    public EntityB getEntityB() {
        return this.entityB;
    }
```

and in EntityB:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entityB")
    public EntityA getEntityA() {
        return this.entityA;
    }
```

So there is a CascadeType.ALL from EntityA to EntityB. I have checked I am not persisting EntityB directly, I print out logs which show me that only the two entities I am looking at are persisted and the entityA instance is pointing to the entityB instance which is pointing  back to the correct entityA instance (and I can see from the stack trace that the persist comes from a cascade). So entityB is persisted because of the cascade from entityA and now entityB is complaining that entityA is transient???

Any ideas what could go wrong here?